# C++ implementation of abstract method not satisfied

Tags: android, c++, inheritance, abstract-class

In an Android project I have a quite messy inheritance situation that I can't fully understand.
This is the error I get compiling:

```
proprietary/external/audioATCmdHandlerServer/AudioCmdHandler.cpp:4458:51: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'android::MediaRecorder'
         m_MediaRecorderClient = new MediaRecorder();
                                                   ^
In file included from proprietary/external/audioATCmdHandlerServer/AudioCmdHandler.h:101:0,
                 from proprietary/external/audioATCmdHandlerServer/AudioCmdHandler.cpp:199:
frameworks/av/include/media/mediarecorder.h:245:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within 'android::MediaRecorder':
 class MediaRecorder : public BnMediaRecorderClient,
       ^
In file included from frameworks/av/include/media/mediarecorder.h:30:0,
                 from proprietary/external/audioATCmdHandlerServer/AudioCmdHandler.h:101,
                 from proprietary/external/audioATCmdHandlerServer/AudioCmdHandler.cpp:199:
frameworks/av/include/media/IMediaRecorderClient.h:32:18: note:     virtual void android::IMediaRecorderClient::readAudio()
     virtual void readAudio() = 0;
```

This is the class MediaRecorder from mediarecorder.h

```
............
.......
#include <media/IMediaRecorderClient.h>
.......
...........

class MediaRecorder : public BnMediaRecorderClient,
                      public virtual IMediaDeathNotifier
{
public:
    MediaRecorder();
    ~MediaRecorder();

    void        died();
    status_t    initCheck();
    status_t    setCamera(const sp<ICamera>& camera, const sp<ICameraRecordingProxy>& proxy);
    status_t    setPreviewSurface(const sp<IGraphicBufferProducer>& surface);
    status_t    setVideoSource(int vs);
    status_t    setAudioSource(int as);
    status_t    setOutputFormat(int of);
    status_t    setVideoEncoder(int ve);
    status_t    setAudioEncoder(int ae);
    status_t    setOutputFile(const char* path);
    status_t    setOutputFile(int fd, int64_t offset, int64_t length);
    status_t    setVideoSize(int width, int height);
    status_t    setVideoFrameRate(int frames_per_second);
    status_t    setParameters(const String8& params);
    status_t    setListener(const sp<MediaRecorderListener>& listener);
    status_t    setClientName(const String16& clientName);
    status_t    prepare();
    status_t    getMaxAmplitude(int* max);
    status_t    start();
    status_t    stop();
    status_t    reset();
    status_t    init();
    status_t    close();
    status_t    release();
    void        notify(int msg, int ext1, int ext2);
    sp<IGraphicBufferProducer>     querySurfaceMediaSourceFromMediaServer();

#ifdef MTK_AOSP_ENHANCEMENT
    status_t    setParametersExtra(const String8& params);
#endif

private:
    void                    doCleanUp();
    status_t                doReset();

    sp<IMediaRecorder>          mMediaRecorder;
    sp<MediaRecorderListener>   mListener;

    // Reference to IGraphicBufferProducer
    // for encoding GL Frames. That is useful only when the
    // video source is set to VIDEO_SOURCE_GRALLOC_BUFFER
    sp<IGraphicBufferProducer>  mSurfaceMediaSource;

    media_recorder_states       mCurrentState;
    bool                        mIsAudioSourceSet;
    bool                        mIsVideoSourceSet;
    bool                        mIsAudioEncoderSet;
    bool                        mIsVideoEncoderSet;
    bool                        mIsOutputFileSet;
    Mutex                       mLock;
    Mutex                       mNotifyLock;
};
```

This is IMediaRecorderClient.h

```
#include <utils/RefBase.h>
#include <binder/IInterface.h>
#include <binder/Parcel.h>

namespace android {

class IMediaRecorderClient: public IInterface
{
public:
    DECLARE_META_INTERFACE(MediaRecorderClient);

    virtual void notify(int msg, int ext1, int ext2) = 0;
    virtual void readAudio() = 0;
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

class BnMediaRecorderClient: public BnInterface<IMediaRecorderClient>
{
public:
    virtual status_t    onTransact( uint32_t code,
                                    const Parcel& data,
                                    Parcel* reply,
                                    uint32_t flags = 0);
};

};
```

And this is an extract from IMediaRecorderClient.cpp, that seems to me implementing the abstract method virtual void readAudio()

```
#include <utils/RefBase.h>
#include <binder/IInterface.h>
#include <binder/Parcel.h>

#include <media/IMediaRecorderClient.h>

namespace android {

enum {
    NOTIFY = IBinder::FIRST_CALL_TRANSACTION,
    READ_AUDIO,
};

class BpMediaRecorderClient: public BpInterface<IMediaRecorderClient>
{
public:
    BpMediaRecorderClient(const sp<IBinder>& impl)
        : BpInterface<IMediaRecorderClient>(impl)
    {
    }

    virtual void notify(int msg, int ext1, int ext2)
    {
        Parcel data, reply;
        data.writeInterfaceToken(IMediaRecorderClient::getInterfaceDescriptor());
        data.writeInt32(msg);
        data.writeInt32(ext1);
        data.writeInt32(ext2);
        remote()->transact(NOTIFY, data, &reply, IBinder::FLAG_ONEWAY);
    }

    virtual void readAudio()
    {
        Parcel data, reply;
        data.writeInterfaceToken(IMediaRecorderClient::getInterfaceDescriptor());
        remote()->transact(READ_AUDIO, data, &reply, IBinder::FLAG_ONEWAY);
    }
};
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: TLDR: The compiler tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: What @DieterLücking says, the error message is 100% clear. But in case it isn't clear to you, the offending code is not instantiating a `BpMediaRecorderClient`. It's instantiating a `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: Thanks guys, that's exactly what I was afraid of. I was hoping that some mechanism that I couldn't get, would solve the issue. So, if I would instantiate MediaRecorder I should define readAudio, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that in the following statement of `AudioCmdHandler.cpp`:

```
    m_MediaRecorderClient = new MediaRecorder();
```

there is an attempt to instantiate the class `MediaRecorder` which is an abstract class.  An abstract class means that it has at least one virtual function which is not defined at all, and in your case it is `readAudio()`.

**How come ?**

The class definition of `MediaRecorder` that you've shown,  doesn't provide `readAudio()`.  But the class inherits from `BnMediaRecorderClient`.  This one doesn't provide `readAudio()` either and inherits from a template `BnInterface<IMediaRecorderClient>`.

I don't know how exactly the template class `BnInterface<...>` is defined, but I guess it is a [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) that extends the interface provided as argument, so that in the end, `MediaRecorder` will indirectly inherit from `IMediaRecorderClient`.

And this one defines this pure virtual function:

```
virtual void readAudio() = 0;
```

**How to solve it ?**

You must provide provide and implement this function in `MediaRecorder` in order to be able to instantiate objects of this class.

Comment: Thanks to you too. Previous answers were correct, bout yours is more complete. I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @4javier: You should probably instantiate `BpMediaRecorderClient` or some other concrete class, not mess with the `MediaRecord` class.